# How to use printstacktrace in Java( Eclipse, android)?

Tags: java, android, printstacktrace

I am developing an android app using eclipse. How to see printstacktrace's output?

Comment: what about `exception.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: @subodh OP probably wants to know how to get result from printStackTrace since there is no console to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printstacktrace's output can be seen in the DDMS ->Logcat view

Please use Log for printing Log's.The message types, and their related method calls are:

```
The Log.e() method is used to log errors.

The Log.w() method is used to log warnings.

The Log.i() method is used to log informational messages.

The Log.d() method is used to log debug messages.

The Log.v() method is used to log verbose messages.

The Log.wtf() method is used to log terrible failures that should never happen. (“WTF” stands for “What a Terrible Failure!” of course.)
```

To see Log output go to DDMS > LogCat

Answer (score 1):

In android development on eclipse, better use logcat. In eclipse, go to Window/Show View/Other... and choose Logcat under Android from the dialog.

[image: Opening Logcat in eclipse]

When you start your app in debug mode, all messages will be logged there. You can use filters to hide messages from system or other apps.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you should prefer `Log` class methods to the `printStackTrace()`. You can see `Log` output inside the logcat in the DDMS. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using it in try, catch context:
catch(Exception E){E.printStackTrace();
I want to know where can I see the  error and cause?

Answer (score 0):

to see printstacktrace's output..

Use `Log` class methods.. like `Log.i`, `Log.v` etc..

To see Log output go to `DDMS > LogCat`

Comment: @ankitrawat your E.printStackTrace() is in DDMS > LogCat.