# Parsing data in android through HttpClient

Tags: android, json

I was parsing JSON data from a URL. Here is my whole code

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

public class GetCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress=new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        progress.setMessage("Please wait while the data is being loaded");
        progress.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSON js=new JSON();
        JSONArray jarray=js.getDataFromUrl(url);
        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
            try{
            JSONObject jobj=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            HashMap<String, String> icity=new HashMap<String, String>();
            String name=jobj.getString(CITY);
            String id=jobj.getString(CITY_ID);

            icity.put(CITY, name);
            icity.put(CITY_ID, id);

            city.add(icity);
        }

        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(progress.isShowing())
            progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    }



ListView lv;
public static final String CITY="city_name";
public static final String CITY_ID="city_id";
String url="http://www.eventdads.com/api/?type=cities";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> city;
ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    city=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    new GetCity().execute();
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(Main.this, city);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**JSON class**

```
public class JSON {
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
JSONArray jarray=null;

public JSONArray getDataFromUrl(String url){
    try{
    DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response=null;
    HttpEntity entity=null;

    HttpGet get=new HttpGet(url);
    response=client.execute(get);
    StatusLine statusline=response.getStatusLine();
    int code=statusline.getStatusCode();
    if(code==200){
    entity=response.getEntity();
    InputStream is=entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader bis=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String msg;
    //StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    while((msg=bis.readLine())!=null){
        builder.append(msg);
    }
    jarray=new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    }
    else {
        Log.e("==>","Failed to Download file");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jarray;
}
}
```

**MyAdapter Class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values;
public static final String CITY="city_name";
public static final String CITY_ID="city_id";

public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr){
    this.context=context;
    values=arr;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    TextView city=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    TextView id=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.cityid);
    ImageView img=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.taylor);
    city.setText(values.get(position).get(CITY));
    id.setText(values.get(position).get(CITY_ID));
    return rowView;
}

}
```

The JSON data is present in the following link:
[JSON data](http://www.eventdads.com/api/?type=cities)

I dont know what the error is. But the Activity isn't showing any data.

Comment: Add a statement in your catch clause to print the stack trace and post it .. e.printStackTrace();

Comment: done it. I am using bluestack app player as emulator. Does that make any difference?

Comment: post the stack of the error you got

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me how to do that step by step. It would be really helpful. I have just started using android.

Comment: After adding the previous statement to your code, when running your app, look at the Logcat in your eclipse and you'll find the printed log of the error
Also check that for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448490/how-to-use-printstacktrace-in-java-eclipse-android

Comment: I have posted the content of the log cat. Please see to it.

Comment: I think it's because of bluestack app player. Try with a real device / Genymotion / default emulator.

Comment: @Mus I tried doing it with a real device, the problem still persists.

Comment: I have inserted my whole code. Hope this helps in finding the error.